# Could MACRO be defined as an array?

Tags: c, arrays, macros

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TEST_ARR  {1, 2, 3}

int main() {
    printf("%d %d %d", TEST_ARR[0], TEST_ARR[1], TEST_ARR[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Surely this program can't run, I just want to make my question clear with this example that whether it is possible to define a MACRO as an array. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: why the c++ tag?

Comment: macros are substituted in directly by the preprocessor. Is `[1,2,3][0]` valid C code?

Comment: possible [dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824703/array-format-for-define-c-preprocessor) ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but like this (C11):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TEST_ARR  (int const[]){1, 2, 3}

int main() {
    printf("%d %d %d", TEST_ARR[0], TEST_ARR[1], TEST_ARR[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

not with `[1, 2, 3]`. (I believe it's safe to say that there's no context in which `[1, 2, 3]` is sensible C code).

Comment: Or alternatively `#define TEST_ARR "\1\2\3"` if stuck with a C89 compiler.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to code {1, 2, 3} rather than [1, 2, 3], ported from python, question modified.

Answer (score -1):

It wont be right. I can explain and proof with a brief summary...please be patience.."**I just tried it also on my compilor**" as you want to examine before with macros..so dont judge my answer according that.

Ques. What is macro in basic?

Ans. basically, its a **symbolic constant**. and it's sytax-

```
  #define macro_symbol defination
```

It means Its a symbol(which is predefined) and can be use whenever require just  using the symbol(might be called identifier).

**keypoint**-->defination is jst paste wherever you used the macro symbol.

so after completing my brief summary, coming to ur code:

```
#define TEST_ARR  {1, 2, 3}
```

it seems be right code. because you jst follow the syntax.

Ok,moving on what you do next-

```
 printf("%d %d %d", TEST_ARR[0], TEST_ARR[1], TEST_ARR[1]);
```

**hey hey!,something wrong occurs, you dont follow my keypoint as describe above.**

Ques. why??

Ans.
**point 1.** Compilor only know about the predefined symbol which is **TEST_ARR** .
 but you want to generate a new macro named as  TEST_ARR[index] from which compilor is not aware before.. so it is wrong.

**Point 2**. there is two general provisions ,Macro in c provides.  one is macro symbols, second is macro functions..

so, what you want to do is not right bro.. search more yourself..thank you:)

Comment: please post your comment..if I helped you in  such manner..? :)

Comment: so that, I can improve my way of explainationing  for further.. :) share your feedback :)