# C preprocessor init array

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm writing a complex macro and I need to pass also array initializer. Basically I have trouble to do:

```
#define INIT_ARR(VAR_NAME,ARR_DATA) int VAR_NAME[] = ARR_DATA
```

then I would call it

```
INIT_ARR(myNm,{1,2,3});
```

but preprocessors interprets any commas (also the one inside curly braces) as new macro parameter so it gives me error:

```
error:  #55-D: too many arguments in invocation of macro "INIT_ARR"
```

preprocessor does not ignore () so I can do:

```
#define INIT_ARR(VAR_NAME,ARR_DATA) int VAR_NAME[] = {ARR_DATA}
INIT_ARR(myNm,(1,2,3));
```

but then it is interpreted as

```
int myNm[] = {(1,2,3)};
```

which is not correct for C.

Is there a way how to do it?? For example remove braces from parameter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array format for #define (C preprocessor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824703/array-format-for-define-c-preprocessor)

Comment: Why do you try to obfuscate your code? There is no need for the macro; if you need a custom type name, use a `typedef` (but as you hav to know how to initialise, this also is not very useful). Don't get too fancy with macros.

Comment: it is not part of question. But it is test code, which test one function with many parameters, and I give expected system state as array initializer. Basically it is 4 lines of code `ret = tested_funct(PARA,PARB,...); if(ret!=0) return PAR_X | ret; ret = chkModuleState({EXP_STATE}) return PAR_Y | ret;` And this repeats 50 times... So I use macro for that. Calling macro repeatedly looks like a table and it is very nice to read what states are tested. True debugging is little obscured...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I cracked it:

```
#define myArgs(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define INIT_ARR(VAR_NAME,ARR_DATA) int VAR_NAME[] = {myArgs ARR_DATA}
INIT_ARR(myArr,(1,2,3,4));
```

will be interpreted correctly as:

```
int myArr[] = {1,2,3,4};
```

[annoying_squid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34182426/1093607) helped me to figure it out...

Comment: Good, but this is not a hack, just a normal behaviour of C Preprocessor. :)

Comment: yes. To me calling of `myArgs` macro seems not so obvious. In first step it will be just set to `myArgs (1,2,3,4)` which will be executed and turn into `1,2,3,4`. Luckily the space between `myArgs` and `(1,2,3,4)` is not a problem. And luckily it is interpreted correctly recursively... But glad you say it is "not a hack". I will use your comment when my boss will ask me what is that ;)

Answer (score 7):

You can use variable number of arguments with the macro as -

```
#define INIT_ARR(VAR_NAME, ...) int VAR_NAME[] = {__VA_ARGS__}
```

Comment: Sorry I modified questions. I did not mention originally that initializer is only part of my macro arguments. I have more arguments so your answer is not valid after my modification... IT seems it is working when modified slightly: `#define INIT_ARR2(VAR_NAME,...) int VAR_NAME[] = {__VA_ARGS__}`. Thx for effort I up you, but I like mine solution better as it keeps at least parenthesis over initialize.

Comment: Whatever suits your needs better :)