# Can I declare an array of constants in the preprocessor?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a code segment that basically does the following

```
int* pins = {2, 3, 5, 7, 10}
for (i = 0; i < NUM_OUTPUTS; ++i{
    output[i].pin = pins[i];
}
```

(note that the numbers do not follow any discernable pattern, so they must be pre declared)

I'd like this to be done in the preprocessor, as the `pins` array won't be touched afterwards.I understand I'll have to probably loop through as I'm not experienced enough with preprocessor macros to make a loop and do the assignment (although that would be cool).

I found [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824703/array-format-for-define-c-preprocessor) but I don't think it's quite what I want.

Can something like this be done? Primarily to free up boot up time/memory usage.

Edit: more information. All I'm trying to do is set up the outputs at compile time - I guess I need to loop through all the outputs in the preprocessor to do so.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to do something more complex than just `const int pins[] = {2, 3,  5,  7, 10}`? Are you trying to set `output[i].pin` to the same values as `pins[i]` at compile time? If so, how is `output` declared? We need more information about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: _Primarily to free up boot up time/memory usage._. Why do you think that the use of preprocessor will help in _free up boot up time/memory usage_?

Comment: Why not simply `const int pins[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 10};` ? Where you could then do `const int NUM_OUTPUTS = sizeof pins / sizeof *pins;`

Comment: How and when is `output` defined?

Answer (score 2):

If the pin array won't be touched afterwards then you can use the compound literal instead of creating `pins` array.

You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PINS (int[]){2, 3, 5, 7, 10}   //compound literal
#define NUM_OUTPUTS (sizeof(PINS)/(sizeof(PINS[0])))
#define INIT(arr) \
        for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_OUTPUTS; i++) { \
            arr[i].pin = PINS[i]; \
        }

struct st_pin {
    int pin;
};

int main()
{
    struct st_pin arr[NUM_OUTPUTS];

    INIT(arr);

    //Printing arr
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_OUTPUTS; ++i){
        printf ("arr[%zu].pin: %d\n", i, arr[i].pin);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
arr[0].pin: 2
arr[1].pin: 3
arr[2].pin: 5
arr[3].pin: 7
arr[4].pin: 10
```

Comment: I like it, one step futher and turn it all into a macro. (despite them being evil `:)`

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_OUTPUTS; ++i)
    output[i].pin = (int []) {2, 3, 5, 7, 10} [i];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take it one step further and define the *compound literal* so that it is expanded as needed:

```
#define PINS (int[]){2, 3, 5, 7, 10}
#define NUM_OUTPUTS (int)(sizeof PINS / sizeof PINS[0])
...
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OUTPUTS; i++)
        output[i].pin = PINS[i];
```

(**note:** the compound literal is supported in C99+, or by compiler extension.)

Comment: Wouldn't this solution result in the same memory usage? I agree it's cleaner code

Comment: There would be virtually no difference in memory usage. The preprocessor simply expands `PINS` to `(int[]){2, 3, 5, 7, 10}` and the same for `NUM_OUTPUTS`